# How to make a button take you to another frame in GUI java?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I would like to go to another frame of Connect Four by clicking the "PLAY ME" button, but I am very confused on how to do so. Here, I have the code for the opening page of connect four and labels and buttons set up on the page. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game implements ActionListener{
   public Game(){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
      frame.setTitle("Connect Four");
      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      JButton play = new JButton();
      play.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,150));
      play.setBackground(Color.RED);
      play.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
      play.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      play.setText("CLICK ME TO PLAY");
      frame.add(play, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


      JPanel north = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      JLabel title = new JLabel("Connect Four");
      north.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 100));
      title.setForeground(Color.RED);
      title.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
      title.setVerticalAlignment(1);
      frame.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      north.add(title);

      JPanel intro = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,1));
      intro.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      JLabel instructions = new JLabel("Instructions");
      instructions.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 70));
      JLabel instructionsPart1 = new JLabel("Both players will be assigned a color, either red or black.");
      JLabel instructionsPart2 = new JLabel("Players will take turns placing the colored discs on to the board.");
      JLabel instructionsPart3 = new JLabel("The OBJECTIVE is to get four of one colored discs in a row.");
      instructionsPart1.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 35));
      instructionsPart2.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 35));
      instructionsPart3.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 35));
      intro.add(instructions);
      intro.add(new JLabel(""));
      intro.add(instructionsPart1);
      intro.add(new JLabel(""));
      intro.add(instructionsPart2);
      intro.add(new JLabel(""));
      intro.add(instructionsPart3);
      intro.add(new JLabel(""));
      frame.add(intro, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(intro);
      }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide Your First Frame And Set Visiblity of second frame to true

```
        btnplay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       second_add second = new second_add();   
       setVisible(false); // Hide current frame
       second.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the frame, change the panel. Instead of using `JFrame`'s `add()` method, use [setContentPane(Container container)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane-java.awt.Container-)

Instead of adding buttons and what not to the frame, create another wrapper panel and use the BorderLayout on that, and then add that panel to the frame:

Example:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
wrapper.add(play, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//etc.   
frame.setContentPane(wrapper);
```

Then, to handle the button click, implement the `ActionListener` interface. Don't do it with the main class - you'll need more than one. Use an anonymous inner class, or a lambda expression. Example:

```
play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setContentPane(someOtherJPanel);
    }
});
```